# Is this LDR and TRIAC circuit advisable for real time application?

Tags: ac, switching, triac, ldr

Would you suggest below circuit?  Will it work for a long time? What are the advantage and disadvantages of this circuit?

[image: LDR Circuit with TRIAC136 and LDR]

https://envirementalb.com/automatic-street-light-circuit/

Comment: *...real time application* For EEs "real time" usually refers to a processor doing things in "real time", meaning doing it immediately. What you mean is "continuous use" or "using it 24/7". The fact that even in cheap (Chinese) commercial products, you will find a slightly more complex (expensive!) circuit means that this circuit is not a good choice. If it was, then **for sure** those products would use it.

Comment: Do people even still use LDRs? Does anyone still make them? Are they even still *legal* considering the cadmium content?

Comment: Unpredictable behavior. May work, may not.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, they're still made and are available off-the-shelf in countries with more laissez-faire treatment of hazardous substances such as the US and China. I believe the EU's limited exemption on them (for pro audio equipment optocouplers) expired  Dec. 31, 2013.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I haven't seen them in the US in years and years, but perhaps they're still used by hobbyists--I've certainly never used them in anything I designed.

Comment: @Hearth There are almost 40 different models in stock at Digikey. A bit expensive. And they're easily available in China at low cost. I put one in a design (in the form of an optoisolator) a few years ago as part the feedback loop of an ultra-low distortion oscillator for testing ADCs etc. Rather a specialized application. I think most of the market would be in outside lighting sockets and motion-activated security lights that shut down when it is light outside. [Here](https://amzn.to/30S7z1A) you can clearly see the CdS photocells.

Answer (score 3):

Disadvantages: For one, it won't typically work at all. Typical gate trigger current for the BT136 is 2.5mA/5mA in quadrants I and III respectively.

The 220K resistor will conduct 1.4mA at the very peak of a 220V waveform, insufficient to turn the triac on in either quadrant. At 110V or at cold temperatures or with a particularly numb sample of BT136 things are considerably worse.

Advantages? I guess it conserves energy.

Comment: If i use 100K Resistor, will it work ?. it gives 2.3mA. My worries are, is there any possibility to LDR burn out in 230vAC and will it gives proper output?

Comment: Is 2.3mA >> 5mA? I don't think it will damage the LDR, the gate-MTI junctions are across it. It will just sit there consuming a bit of current.

Answer (score 1):

220k will not work. I used 220 R (ohm) ressistor then worked. Can't beleve. I thought it will burn. But no.Triac is same.